# Column transform in Spark MLlib

Tags: python, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-mllib

I have read [Spark MLlib doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/ml-features.html#binarizer) for feature transform, but I am still confused about two simple cases:

1.How to deal with single column flexible?
For example, I have one column named "date", it's "YYYY-MM-DD" format, I want to generate one new column called "week" based on "date". If use pandas.Dataframe, it could be done with Series.apply, my quesion is how to do that in Spark MLlib?

2.How to generate new column based on multi-columns?
For example, I want to calculate roi based on spend and income, it's simple in pandas.DataFrame:

```
df['roi'] = (df['income'] - df['spend'])/df['spend']
```

For Spark.MLlib, I find SQLTransformer may be used for the same work, but I am not sure

Could any guy tell me how to deal with that in Spark.MLlib? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A clean option is to define your own function, and apply to your `DataFrame` using `withColumn()`. Note that this has nothing to do with `MLlib` as that refers to the machine learning module of `Spark`.

```
from pyspark.sql.types import FloatType
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

def roiCalc(income, spend): # Define function
  return((income - spend)/spend)

roiCalculator = udf(roiCalc, FloatType()) # Convert to udf
df.withColumn("roi", roiCalculator(df["income"],df["spend"])) # Apply to df
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,that's what I was confused before